# PHP: Random "1" outputted to the screen

Tags: php, if-statement, include

I have the following code:

```
if ($currentStage == 7)
{
  echo include("include/contentP7.php");

}
```

The content of "content7.php" exists however it is blank.
But when $currentStage is equal to 7 the page is displayed and a random "1" is outputted although "content7.php" is blank.

I assume it may be to do with returning "True" to the if statement. Why is this and how can I remove this "1".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`include` returns `TRUE` upon success, when echoed, it becomes 1.

Omit the `echo` statement:

```
if ($currentStage == 7) {
    include("include/contentP7.php");
}
```

Include should be on its own.

Answer (score 1):

include probably returns `true`(1) when `include`i successful. Remove the `echo` to get rid of the 1

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($currentStage == 7)
{
    include("include/contentP7.php");
}
```

I don't understand what the other parts were intended to do. If you wanted to echo a value from contentP7, place that content into a variable (perhaps a HEREDOC or something). Then include and echo like this:

```
if ($currentStage == 7)
{
    include("include/contentP7.php");
    echo $contentP7_variable;
}
```

The "1" or True value might be returned because you are echoing the returned status of the include() but I am not sure how since php.net's manual explains that it is a language construct. I can't test this right now, unfortunately.